# How to not include duplicates in SQL with inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to list the customer's name, last name, email, phone number, address, and the title of the show they are going. I am not supposed to list duplicate names of the customer, but unfortunately, if 1 customer is seeing different shows, their name appears twice. I am still getting duplicates despite using DISTINCT and GROUP BY. What should I include to not have duplicate names of customers?

```
select distinct c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email, c.phone, c.address, s.title
from customer c
inner join ticket tk on tk.customer_id = c.customer_id
inner join `show` s on s.show_id = tk.show_id
group by c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email, c.phone, c.address, s.title
order by c.last_name;
```

Comment: Isn't that the normal behavior if you want to include show.title?  Without that detail you wouldn't even add those joins at all, no? And BTW it is nonsense to have distinct when you do it by using group by. If title has no importance and you mean to select any show.title they attended then you could use max(s.title) or min(s.title) as Title.

Comment: Do you mean you want only the first row per customer to have their name? A detail like that should probably be handled by the application

Comment: I don't know if mySQL has somthing similar, but say in postgreSQL there is string_agg() that you could aggregate all the shows they attended to a siingle one.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` would be the MySQL equivalent.

Comment: You only select from `customer c`.  Put the rest of the tables in a `WHERE EXISTS(...)` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to aggregate by `title`, since, as you pointed out, there could be multiple titles. Instead, remove it from `group by` and aggregate it via `group_concat`:

```
select c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email, c.phone, c.address, group_concat(s.title)
from customer c
inner join ticket tk on tk.customer_id = c.customer_id
inner join `show` s on s.show_id = tk.show_id
group by c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email, c.phone, c.address
order by c.last_name;
```

You don't need the `distinct` keyword either. Remember: if you want to aggregate by a field, then more often than not you need to avoid grouping by it. The fact that due to `title` the records have got duplicated proves that it's a column to be aggregated.

Comment: I was thinking of using concat too. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jack happy to help. If this answer has led you towards the solution, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK a quick check on mySQL documentation reveals that you could use Group_Concat() for your purpose:

```
select c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email, c.phone, c.address, group_concat(s.title) as Title
from customer c
inner join ticket tk on tk.customer_id = c.customer_id
inner join `show` s on s.show_id = tk.show_id
group by c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email, c.phone, c.address, s.title
order by c.last_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar queries with the same issue as you're having.  This is how I would write this:

```
select distinct c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email, c.phone, c.address, s.title
from customer c
left join ticket tk on tk.customer_id = c.customer_id
left join `show` s on s.show_id = tk.show_id
group by c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email, c.phone, c.address, s.title
order by c.last_name;
```